# C# like Dependency injection for C++ on embedded device

Tags: c++, dependency-injection, embedded

I was wondering if it would be possible to create a C# like syntax for dependency injection. My device is running constantly and acting more or less like a service. I came up with the following. My question, is it a good idea to use this, or something along the lines of this?

````
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

class ServiceContext {
private:
    // Mapping of interface type names to shared pointers of concrete instances
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<void>> services;

public:
    // Add a service to the context with dependency injection
    template <typename Interface, typename Concrete>
    void addSingleton() {
        // Ensure that the Concrete class implements the specified interface
        static_assert(std::is_base_of<Interface, Concrete>::value,
                      "Concrete class must implement the specified interface");

        // Generate a key using the type name of the specified interface
        const std::string key = typeid(Interface).name();

        // Check if a singleton with the specified interface already exists
        if (services.find(key) != services.end()) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Singleton with interface already exists in ServiceContext");
        }

        // Create an instance of the Concrete class and store it in the services map
        auto concreteInstance = std::make_shared<Concrete>(*this);
        services[key] = std::static_pointer_cast<void>(concreteInstance);
    }

    // Get a service from the context
    template <typename Interface>
    std::shared_ptr<Interface> getService() const {
        // Find the service in the map using the type name of the specified interface
        auto it = services.find(typeid(Interface).name());
        if (it != services.end()) {
            // If found, return the service casted to the specified interface type
            return std::static_pointer_cast<Interface>(it->second);
        }
        // If not found, return nullptr
        return nullptr;
    }
};

class Builder {
public:
    ServiceContext Services;

    // Build the application
    template <typename T>
    std::shared_ptr<T> build() const {
        return std::make_shared<T>(Services);
    }
};

class ILogger {
public:
    virtual void PrintLine(const std::string& message) = 0;
    virtual ~ILogger() = default;
};

class ActualLogger : public ILogger {
public:
    ActualLogger(const ServiceContext& services)
    {
    }
    
    void PrintLine(const std::string& message) override {
        std::cout << "[Logger] " << message << std::endl;
    }
};

class IButtons {
public:
    virtual void Click() = 0; //This is only so I can simulate a button click
    virtual void AddOnClickCallback(std::function<void()> callback) = 0;
    virtual ~IButtons() = default;
};

class ActualButtons : public IButtons {
    std::vector<std::function<void()>> onClickCallbacks;

public:
    ActualButtons(const ServiceContext& services)
    {
    }
    
     //This is only so I can simulate a button click
    void Click() override {
        std::cout << "Button clicked!" << std::endl;
        // Notify all subscribers
        for (const auto& callback : onClickCallbacks) {
            callback();
        }
    }

    void AddOnClickCallback(std::function<void()> callback) override {
        onClickCallbacks.push_back(callback);
    }
};


class IDisplay {
public:
    virtual void Print(const std::string& message) = 0;
    virtual ~IDisplay() = default;
};

class ActualDisplay : public IDisplay {
    std::shared_ptr<ILogger> logger;

public:
    ActualDisplay(const ServiceContext& services)
        : logger(services.getService<ILogger>()) 
    {
        
    }

    void Print(const std::string& message) override {
        logger->PrintLine(message);
    }
};

class IGUI {
public:
    virtual void Run() = 0;
    virtual ~IGUI() = default;
};

class ActualGUI : public IGUI {
    std::shared_ptr<IDisplay> display;
    std::shared_ptr<IButtons> buttons;
    std::shared_ptr<ILogger> logger;

public:
    ActualGUI(const ServiceContext& services)
        : display(services.getService<IDisplay>())
        , buttons(services.getService<IButtons>())
        , logger(services.getService<ILogger>()) {
    }

    void Run() override {
        logger->PrintLine("GUI is running...");
        buttons->Click();  // Simulate a button click
        display->Print("Hello from the GUI");
    }
};

class MainApp {
    std::shared_ptr<IGUI> gui;

public:
    MainApp(const ServiceContext& services)
        : gui(services.getService<IGUI>()) {
    }

    void Run() {
        gui->Run();
    }
};

int main() {
    // Example usage
    Builder builder;

    builder.Services.addSingleton<IDisplay, ActualDisplay>();
    builder.Services.addSingleton<ILogger, ActualLogger>();
    builder.Services.addSingleton<IButtons, ActualButtons>();  // Register the buttons
    builder.Services.addSingleton<IGUI, ActualGUI>();

    auto app = builder.build<MainApp>();

    if (app) {
        app->Run();
    }

    return 0;
}

```
````

Comment: Have you considered `std::any`? `std::any_cast` performs `typeid` check, which could be used in your container, although that would limit it to one object of type per type.

Comment: Good suggestion. One object per type is a good thing, since you don't want multiple instances in this case. BTW, its already limited by checking the interface type.